# ADD_DATE() not working with where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I want to get all my records from the table that are in status 1 from the last 4 hours with respect to creation_time (in my case creation_time is the column on which I want to apply +4 hour check). for that, I tried ADD_DATE() with the below query but it's not returning any records even I have the same records available.

```
select id,name,status,creation_time, DATE_ADD(creation_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) as modified_time 
from booking
where status=1 and creation_time >= DATE_ADD(creation_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
```

anyone, please let me know where I am doing wrong with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A date/time value is never greater than *that same value* with four hours added on.

If you want the last four hours, I would expect a `where` clause like this:

```
where status = 1 and
      creation_time >= now() - interval 4 hour
```

Note the use of `now()` for the comparison.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  This would appear to do exactly what you are asking for.